# I'm trying to scrape a table from a website and cannot get the position column to show

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.virtualpronetwork.com/apps/fvpaa/simulation/freeagents/13/ANY/"  

page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)


with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:  
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
    f.write("player: %s, Team: %s, Pos: %s" % \
    (tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text))
```

I also would like to be able to extract multiple pages at the same time. I think I can do that with an id command and adding (+ id) to the end of the url but I'm not sure. I want to write this into an excel file which I know I can do with csv as well but I don't know how to put it into separate columns. The main things, however, are getting the last column (positions) to show up and to be able to extract multiple pages at the same time even if I need an input file. The website posted is the one I'm trying to extract the data from.

My output is attached as an image[image: Output]